# How to access the value without foreach in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

In my PHP code, I noticed that I can access my value only with a foreach. Can anyone explain why?

```
return view('pages.temp_page_course', [
        'page' => $this->course($slug),
    ]);


public function course($slug)
{
    $course = Course::where('slug', $slug)->get();
    return $course;
}
```

With this code, I can access the value.

```
@foreach($page as $key => $course)
    {{ $course->title }}
@endforeach
```

How do I access the value without doing a foreach?

Thank you very much

Comment: can we see `course()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$course = Course::where('slug', $slug)->get();` will fetch an array of courses.

Try [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) instead, `$course = Course::where('slug', $slug)->first();` will fetch only 1 and will remove the need for the loop.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much, I understand better. It's work fine!

Comment: @E_p yes, I had to wait

Answer (score 2):

Replace get() with toArray(), that will load results into `$course` as an array so you can access it as an array

```
public function course($slug)
{
    $course = Course::where('slug', $slug)->toArray();
    return $course;
}
```